# How to apply the deprecated attribute to a using statement

Tags: attributes, c++14, deprecated, type-alias

How do I apply a deprecated attribute to a using statement, it seems weird that I can apply it to a `typedef` by not a `using`

```cpp
// Cannot do this
[[deprecated("Use a real int you wimp")]]
using Foo = int;

// This works just fine
[[deprecated("Use a real int you wimp")]]
typedef int Bar;

int main(int, char *[])
{
    Foo i = 43;

    (void)i;

    Bar j = 34;

    (void)j;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```cpp
using Foo [[deprecated("Use a real int you wimp")]] = int;
```